# compare 2 arrays and remove duplicates ? Java

Tags: java, arrays, compare

so I am trying to compare 2 huge lists of text in java . The texts might look like this :

list1 : value 1 , value 2 , value 3 ...
list2 : value 1604 , value 7000 , value 1 ...

The point is I like to compare from list 1 to each line in list 2 ( each value is in own line ) and remove duplicates from list 2 write a ARRAY 3 to file . this is what I got :

EDIT :

```
    File haveFile = new File("Combine Without Dups.txt");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(haveFile));
    String line ;
    String list = null ;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    list = line ;

    }

    File compareFile = new File("database.txt");
    BufferedReader br2 = null;
    br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(compareFile));
    String line2 ;
    String list2 = null ;

    while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {

    list2 = line2 ;

    list2.removeAll(list);
```

Comment: Are the values unique per list?  As in, can a list have two equivalent values?

Comment: you can use HashSet<String> instead of ArrayList, duplications are removed automatically

Comment: Why do this: BufferedReader br = null; br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(haveFile)); ?

Comment: yes they are unique . the list 1 contains 12000 names in lines one name per line. the list 2 contains a 42000 names That I need to remove those 12000 names

Comment: @kon its the onlyWay I know how to read and it works so far . I don't need it to be perfect just get the job done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read all lines from the first file into a `Set<String>` (not a `List`), and similarly from the second file. For example using `LinkedHashSet`s (to retain insertion order).

Then do:

```
// set2 contains lines in second file, set1 in first file
set2.removeAll(set1);
```

Then write the contents of `set2` into the result file.

Note that this supposes there are no duplicate values.

If you use Guava, you can also use [`Sets.difference()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) to compute the difference between the sets, and [`Files.readLines()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to read lines from a file directly (note, this is NOT Java 7's `Files` -- if you do use Java 7, you can use [`Files.readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) -- and throw `File` out of the window for good measure)

---

Full code using Java 7:

```
final Path path1 = Paths.get("/path/to/file1");
final Path path2 = Paths.get("/path/to/file2");
final Path outfile = Paths.get("/path/to/outfile");

final List<String> list1 = Files.readAllLines(path1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final List<String> list2 = Files.readAllLines(path2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

list2.removeAll(list1);

Files.write(outfile, list2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I want the third file that I extract to be each word in its own line and the same format as the other 2 . Just without 12000 specific lines . Not sure making a string will give me the names in the same format ?

Comment: @anno I fail to understand what you mean by "the same format as the other 2". Of course it will write with the same format.

Comment: I mean the file 3 will have around 30000 names each in its own line not one after each other

Comment: That is not the problem. `FileWriter` has `.newLine()`, just write a newline after each name you write

Comment: not sure how to use removeAll says the method is undefined . ( I use java eclipse on win7 64-bit )

Comment: Eh? `Set` does define `.removeAll()`. You must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: quote "The method removeAll(String) is undefined for the type String"

Comment: Look at the answer again: I tell you to remove the _set_ of strings from the first file, not string by string

Comment: sorry I am noob I don't get it I Edited original post to what I have at the moment . plz take a look Edit acually I am using java 7 ! let me change it

Comment: OK, see edit. But please learn how to manipulate collections. Code provided like this won't help you progressing into mastering the language.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean combine list1+list2 then remove duplicates
use a normal Set collection, as it containts no duplicates, when you add values it will remove dpulicates automatically,

Comment: no I want to remove every single name that is in file 1 from file 2 . no combine .

Comment: ok then a single for loop resolves the issue
for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++)
{  if( !list2.contains(list1.get(i)))
    { list3.add(list1.get(i)); }
}

then write list3 to file

Comment: ok I think I got it but it seems like I cant write to file with FileWriter an array .

Comment: FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); 
       fw.write(list3);          fw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
       fw.close();

Comment: Acually I don't eclipse says I need to cast .get .whatever that means I don't know

Comment: eclipse says what? press f2 to focus and then copy it here

Answer (score 0):

1.Read 2 file into 2 ArrayList
2.Create 2 for loop which one is inside the other.first loop should iterate on the first list and second loop should iterate in the second list.
3.compare each value of list 1 and list 2.if any equal value remove it.

Comment: that is kinda what I look for ! I need time coding it as I am complete noob !